# aws s3 meta tag for redirect using putObject

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

This is successfully creating the object, but I am having trouble writing the meta tag for website redirect.

Has anybody had success with this?

```
$result = $client->putObject(array(
    'Bucket' => $hello,
    'Key'    => $hellokey,
    'Body'   => 'the body',
    'ContentType' => 'text/html',
    'Metadata'   => array(
       'Website Redirect Location' => 'http://www.cnn.com/'
    )
));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [API docs for `putObject`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/latest/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_putObject), you may be looking for the `WebsiteRedirectLocation` parameter. Why don't you give this a try:

```
$result = $client->putObject(array(
    'Bucket' => $hello,
    'Key' => $hellokey,
    'Body' => 'the body',
    'ContentType' => 'text/html',
    'WebsiteRedirectLocation' => 'http://www.cnn.com/'
));
```